# casting of types - java

Tags: object, casting, declaration, instantiation

Good day, All!
Here is a code:

```
    class Monster {
}

class Dragon extends Monster {
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("I'm a dragon");
    }
}

class Orc extends Monster {
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("I'm an orc");
    }
}

public class CastingExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Monster monster1 = new Dragon();
        Monster monster2 = new Orc();

        ((Dragon)monster1).say();
        ((Orc)monster2).say();
    }
}
```

I understand what for casting. But my question is why at first the author made id like `Monster monster1 = new Dragon();`
Why not `Dragon monster1 = new Dragon();` from the beginning? I mean why sometime...or in which situations programmers need to declare type A, but  create B object. `A a = new B();`?

Comment: As you can see Monster is generic type for Dragon and Orc its mean that Dragon is a Monster and Orc is a Monster but Orc is not a Dragon. Such kind of code gives you a flexibility when you need work with monster1 and monster2. That looks like it should be some logic between Monster monster2 = new Orc(); and ((Dragon)monster1).say();

Comment: That's OK! But I can use 'Dragon monster1 = new Dragon();' and 'Orc monster2 = new Orc();' and I'll get that flexibility. Why do I need generic (or base) class at the left part at all?